# What is the right way to check floating-point variables for exact value equality in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point

I need to check if a floating-point (`double`) variable `a` value exactly equals floating-point (`double`) variable `b` value. I know floating-point types don't have exact matches to all the decimal values and such a comparison does not make much "physical sense" but I still need to check if the values stored are exactly the same from the binary point of view. Is using the `==` operator ok in this case?

Comment: Are you so sure you have the exact values stored in your double variables that you think you do in the first place?

Comment: I don't care if the values actually equal to real-world values they represent (I am actually sure in most cases they don't). The variables are the originals I seek to compare in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` and `y` are both of type `double`, then `x == y` if and only if `x` and `y` are binary-equivalent. So, if what you are truly looking for is binary-equivalence, then `==` is exactly what you want to be using.

Comment: Not true.  NaNs and signed zeroes break this.

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to test whether two `double`s are **numerically equal**, you want to test `a == b`.

If you are trying to test whether two `double`s **have the same binary representation**, you need to get at the binary representation first.  It appears that `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` is a function that will do this for you.  Then you make an **integer** comparison between the two bit patterns.

There are a couple of differences between numerical equality and bit-for-bit equality.  First, if either `a` or `b` is a `NaN`, then `a == b` will be false even if `a` and `b` have the same bit pattern.  Second, there are two zeroes in IEEE floating-point---a positive zero and a negative zero.  If `a` is the positive zero and `b` is the negative zero, then `a == b` will be true, even though `a` and `b` have different bit patterns.

Answer (score 1):

For **exact** equality, it's just `if (a == b)` or `if (a.Equals(b))` (note: the results of those two expressions can be different if `NaN` is involved.

But if you want to account for floating point rounding error (and you should), it's more complicated. In theory, you use the [`double.Epsilon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constant to check whether the difference between your numbers ends up between positive and negative epsilon. In practice, it's commonly believed that the framework got this wrong ([see this reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6684987-9934-4798-9113-eb6a39efe1a6/doubleepsilon-what-is-it-good-for?forum=clr)) and made it way too small (The MSDN documentation [specifically mentions this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) — see the note near the middle of the page), such that you'll need to use your own small constant. 1.0e-12 or 1.0e-15 are common default choices, but what you're really supposed to do is analyze the math to determine what your rounding error potential actually is, and use an "epsilon" constant for your specific problem based on that. Unfortunately, this process is easy to get wrong, hence the common defaults mentioned above.

Comment: He asked how to check whether two `double`s are equal, not where two doubles are within some epsilon of each other.  These are two very, very different things, and your advice is inappropriate.

Comment: Everything that is wrong in this answer it summarized in the words “it's commonly believed”.

Comment: Machine epsilon is not intended for fuzzy equality checking